# Script doesn't Reflect frontend

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, requirejs

I added  script file to view/templates/chat.phtml its not reflect for me,

This is My Layout File view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="tawk.chat">
            <block class="Chennaibox\Tawk\Block\chat"  template="Chennaibox_Tawk::chat.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is My Block File:

```
/**
 * Backend form key content block
 */
namespace Chennaibox\Tawk\Block;

class Chat extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

This is Phtml File: view/templates/chat.phtml

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $_Tawk_API={},$_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/573e8d5d9ac6de9e4f917161/default';
        s1.charset='UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

chat.phtml file not reflect in front end suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing we need to know that Magento uses Require Js to asynchronously load  js files. So, our custom js should be called via Require Js.

First, we should create our module:

[image]

app/code/Chennaibox/Tawk/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Chennaibox_Tawk" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Chennaibox/Tawk/Block/Chat.php

```
<?php

namespace Chennaibox\Tawk\Block;

class Chat extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

app/code/Chennaibox/Tawk/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Chennaibox_Tawk',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Chennaibox/Tawk/view/frontend/templates/chat.phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        //Your code lines should be here
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $_Tawk_API={},$_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
            var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/573e8d5d9ac6de9e4f917161/default';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, in your custom theme:

[image]

app/design/frontend/{Vendor theme}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Chennaibox\Tawk\Block\Chat"  template="Chennaibox_Tawk::chat.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The result:

[image]